# Call a method or action after the Iteration is completed in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

So by default I have an state that shows loading, for example: `[loading, setLoading] = useState(true)`, and I do have an useEffect called after the data comes from the api, and then iterate the data, and what I want to do is when the iteration and the stuff inside the map are completed call the `setLoading(true)` but this doesn't work.

Here is the source:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (orders.isLoading !== true && events.length === 0)
      orders.orders.map((order) => {
        const day = order.appointment.substring(0, 10);
        const time = order.appointment.substring(11, 16);

        const date = {
          id: order._id,
          day: new Date(day).getTime(),
          title: ` Meeting with ${order.customer.firstName}`,
          url: `/order/${order._id}`,
        };

        setEvents((prev) => [...prev, date]);
      });

    dispatchCalEvent({ type: 'fetch', payload: events });
    setLoading(false);
  }, [orders]);
```

The problem here is that the `setLoading(false)` is called before the iteration completes.

Answer (score 0):

I think the below should work.
I've just added the `i` parameter to the `map` function to track the index and then inside the `map` loop, I check at the end if this index is the last one in the array, then call `setIsLoading` if it is.

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (orders.isLoading !== true && events.length === 0)
      orders.orders.map((order, i) => {
        const day = order.appointment.substring(0, 10);
        const time = order.appointment.substring(11, 16);

        const date = {
          id: order._id,
          day: new Date(day).getTime(),
          title: ` Meeting with ${order.customer.firstName}`,
          url: `/order/${order._id}`,
        };

        setEvents((prev) => [...prev, date]);
        if(i === orders.orders.length-1) setIsLoading(false);
      });

    dispatchCalEvent({ type: 'fetch', payload: events });

  }, [orders]);
```